# PPPoE reports network is down

Tags: ppp

When I try to connect to the Internet using `pon provider`, I get this error:

```
error sending pppoe packet: Network is down
error receiving pppoe packet: Network is down
```

If I configure the Internet with `pppoeconf`, then run `pon provider`, the connection works. I should not have to run `pppoeconf` every time I turn on my computer. How can I connect to the Internet, with `pon` without having to run `pppoeconf` every time?

Update:

When I installed Debian, the installer could not establish a DHCP connection, so I skipped the "Configure network" option. I have found, running this command allows me to start the Internet, without having to configure `pppoeconf` again.

```
ifconfig eth0 up
pon dsl-provider
```

Is there some place I should add `ifconfig eth0 up` so that it begins during startup and shutdown or when I run `pon` or `poff`?

Comment: Watch your system logs (files under `/var/log`) to see what `pppoeconf` does that `pon` doesn't do. Post all the logs that appear while you run `pppoeconf` or `pon`.

Comment: Is there any particular log which I should be checking? There are many logs, so I don't know how to find these.

Comment: Look at the ones that changed in the last few minutes: `ls -ltr /var/log`

Comment: According to this, after running `pppoeconf`, no logs were changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout `man 5 interfaces`. The `/etc/network/interfaces` file tells bunch of scripts (debian package `ifupdown`) how to bring up various network interfaces. You'd find stanzas like the following in them:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

The '`auto eth0`' line tells the `ifupdown` bunch of scripts to '`UP`' the `eth0` interface when asked to `UP` everything. The system startup script normally requests that without having to add any lines in it/them.

So, I suggest you have a look at your `/etc/network/interfaces` file to see if you have an `iface` line for `eth0`. If you do check for presence of `auto eth0`.

If you dont have a DHCP server on the network, you could `static` IP and set an [auto-IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-IP) value (for e.g. 169.254.1.1) for the static address. If you chose to use '`manual`' method you could add a simple script like the following to `/etc/network/if-up.d/` :

```
#!/bin/bash
test "${IFACE}" = "eth0" && ifconfig ${IFACE} up
exit 0
```

You'd need `auto eth0` if you want it to be automagically brought up during bootup. You can test this (and your script) by using `ifup -a` and `ifdown -a` which acts on all the interfaces marked as `auto`.

Comment: There already is a line for `auto eth0`, the next line is `iface eth0 inet manual`. When I change `manual` to `dhcp`, durign startup, DHCPDISCOVER spends about a minute testing various ports and finally reports, "No DHCPOFFERS received." I do not think that my ISP uses DHCP.

Comment: I was assuming your eth0 normally gets a LAN address. Also, It does not look like setting it manual would `UP` the interface. You would have to add a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d` to do the job. I'll edit my answer to incorporate a sample.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a pppoe connection, you can do it in the `/etc/network/interfaces` via 'Debian' or 'Ubuntu' way like:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet ppp
    provider dsl-provider
```

You can find this solution in /usr/share/doc/pppoe/README.Debian

Edit:

If you want to start connection manually, don't use a line `auto eth0` and connection you can start by `ifup eth0` command.

Comment: According to `README.Debian`, this should be used if you want to start the Internet during startup, which is not what I wish to do. Adding these lines results in an error during startup that `/dev/modem` was not found.

Comment: The exact error is: `/var/log/syslog:Feb 23 20:48:16 * pppd[*]: In file /etc/ppp/peers/provider: unrecognized option '/dev/modem'`. Note that I don't use a `provider` file, but a `dsl-provider` file, so I do not know why it is looking for the wrong file.

Comment: @Village In my case I had a exactly same block in `/etc/network/interfaces` and for me Ubuntu used file dsl-provider, which was a correct??? And if you want to start connection manually, see my updated answer.

Comment: Simple solution of problem with a dsl-provider and provider is deleting a /etc/ppp/peers/provider file and make link dsl-provider -> provider. But it's not as good as I would like.